# Keras: Input tensor must be of rank 3, 4 or 5 but was 2

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to build a SIMON model based of this example([link](https://github.com/algorine/simon/blob/master/Simon/Simon.py#L116)). Below is how I'm building the 2 models: (1) sentence encoder (sentEncoder) which feeds into (2) doc encoder (docModel).

When I try to fit, I'm getting the following error.

> Input tensor must be of rank 3, 4 or 5 but was 2.

My input is of shape (3003, 30, 28), i.e. (samples,sent max length, one-hot encoded character).

```
    maxLength = 30
    max_cells = 3003
    charMap = {'a': 1,'b': 2, 'c': 3,'d': 4,'e': 5,'f': 6,
           'g': 7,'h': 8, 'i': 9, 'j': 10, 'k': 11,
           'l': 12,'m': 13, 'n': 14, 'o': 15, 'p': 16,
           'q': 17,'r': 18, 's': 19, 't': 20, 'u': 21,
           'v': 22,'w': 23, 'x': 24, 'y': 25, 'z': 26,
           ' ': 27}
    maxChars = len(charMap)+1
    x_train = np.zeros((max_cells, maxLength, maxChars), dtype='int32')
    y_train = np.zeros((max_cells, 3), dtype='int32')
    
    def buildSentModel(sentModelInput):
        layer = Conv1D(10,
                         5,
                         padding='valid',
                         activation='relu',
                         strides=1)(sentModelInput)
        layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=12, return_sequences=False))(layer)
        return Model(input=sentModelInput, output=layer)
        
    
    
    def buildDocModel(sentModel, docInput):
        layer = TimeDistributed(sentModel)(docInput)
        
        #layer = Flatten()(layer)
        layer = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(layer)
        
        return Model(input=docInput, output=layer)
        
    
    sentModelInput = Input(shape=(30,28), dtype='float32')
    sentModel = buildSentModel(sentModelInput);
    
    docModel = buildDocModel(sentModel, sentModelInput);
    
    docModel.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
    docModel.fit(x_train, y_train, steps_per_epoch=20,epochs=100, shuffle=True)
```

Here is the whole error:

> File "C:\temp\Simon\TempSimonNames.py", line 107, in 
> model = buildDocModel(sentModel, sentModelInput);
>
> File "C:\temp\Simon\TempSimonNames.py", line 94, in buildDocModel
> layer = TimeDistributed(sentModel)(docInput)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
> line 75, in symbolic_fn_wrapper
> return func(*args, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\base_layer.py",
> line 489, in **call**
> output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\wrappers.py",
> line 250, in call
> y = self.layer.call(inputs, **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
> line 583, in call
> output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\engine\network.py",
> line 740, in run_internal_graph
> layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\layers\convolutional.py",
> line 163, in call
> dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate[0])
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\tensorflow_backend.py",
> line 3671, in conv1d
> **kwargs)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py",
> line 917, in convolution_v2
> name=name)
>
> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\ops\nn_ops.py",
> line 969, in convolution_internal
> "Input tensor must be of rank 3, 4 or 5 but was {}.".format(n + 2))
>
> ValueError: Input tensor must be of rank 3, 4 or 5 but was 2.

Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to have mixed up some of your variables and shapes.

According to your code, sent_model is a model receiving a sentence consisting of up to 30 characters, hence the input shape of (30, 28) (even though I am wondering why your sentences only have up to 30 characters, that seems to be not that much).

Your doc_model now is supposed to apply the sent_model to each sentence of the document. So the input shape of your document should be (num_sentences_per_doc, 30, 28).

Now to the problem: You pass the same input layer to both models. This does not make any sense, since the two models need to have different input layers. The shape of sentModelInput (the only input layer you defined) matches the input shape for your sent_model, but has too few dimensions for your doc_model, since this model needs a shape of (num_sentences_per_doc, 30, 28) as described earlier. So the fix to all of this would be the following:

1. Use two different input layers for both models.
2. Make sure that the input layers actually have the correct shape.

This altered code should give you an idea of what you need to do. If you want to use the flatten approach that is currently commented out, your documents will need to have a fixed number of sentences, so I will call this num_sents_per_doc. If you want to build a model that can handle documents of variable lengths, then you need to set the input shape of docInput to (None, 30, 28) and use a neural network structure that can handle this variable length input.

```
def buildSentModel():
    sentModelInput = Input(shape=(30,28), dtype='float32')
    layer = Conv1D(10,
                     5,
                     padding='valid',
                     activation='relu',
                     strides=1)(sentModelInput)
    layer = Bidirectional(LSTM(units=12, return_sequences=False))(layer)
    return Model(input=sentModelInput, output=layer)
    


def buildDocModel():
    docInput = Input(shape=(num_sents_per_doc, 30,28), dtype='float32')
    layer = TimeDistributed(sentModel)(docInput)
    
    #layer = Flatten()(layer)
    layer = Dense(3, activation='sigmoid')(layer)
    
    return Model(input=docInput, output=layer)
    

sentModel = buildSentModel();
docModel = buildDocModel(sentModel);

docModel.compile(optimizer="adam", loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
docModel.fit(x_train, y_train, steps_per_epoch=20,epochs=100, shuffle=True)
```

Comment: Marc, I can't thank you enough for breaking this down for me! Your code worked for me, but I had to make a small change. I had to Flatten() before the Dense layer in  buildDocModel. It complained, "expected dense_4 to have 4 dimensions, but got array with shape (3003, 3)".  Wont the TimeDistributed layer break down axis 1 (sentences) and pass just the 2D to Dense? Why would it be expecting 4D?

Comment: You're welcome! So I think that the TimeDistributed layer just applies the sentModel to every one of the 3003 sentences. This means that, if the input to your buildDocModel has shape (3003, 30, 28), the sentModel is applied to each of the 3003 tensors of shape (30, 28). The output of your sentModel now has shape (12,) as far as I can see, so the output of your TimeDistributed layer should be (3003, 12). If you now use your dense layer on this, it will be applied to each of the 3003 12-dimensional tensors individually. This results in an output shape of (3003, 3) (because the layer

Comment: has 3 neurons). This is probably not what you want, so instead you use the flatten layer, which basically just turns the two-dimensional output of the TimeDistributed layer of shape (3003, 12) into a 1-D tensor of shape 3003*12 = (36036,), which you can then apply the dense layer to (resulting in a final shape of (3,). Does this help you with your question?

Comment: ok thats really, helpful. Can I pls ask another quick question? When using a Bidirectional wrapper around an LSTM, is that the same as using Forward LSTM + Backward LSTM + concatenation layer?

Comment: It seems so, at least that is what I see if I look at the documentation: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Bidirectional  There might be differences if you set some different parameters, for example the merge_mode or specifying a different backwards_layer, but if you dont do that then it should be the same.

Comment: Hi Marc, can I pls bother you with another question? So my input is of shape [document,sentence,char], so the Conv1D layers in buildSentModel() are convolving on the characters of the sentence. Now, if i add Conv1D layers in buildDocModel() after the TimeDistributed(), then does it mean that it's convolving on the sentences as a whole? Thanks!

Comment: No, since you do another processing step in your SentModel. As you mentioned, you apply Conv1D to the chars, which will result in another sequence of outputs. Afterwards, you apply a Bidirectional LSTM to the Conv1D outputs, and this will return a single (12-dimensional) vector to represent your whole sentence. Thus, the output of your TimeDistributed layer will be (num_sentences, 12), where you have 12-dimensional vectors for each sentence. If you now apply Conv1D here, you basically combine neighboring sentences to get information out of small groups of sentences.

Comment: This Conv1D might actually make sense, but it might make even more sense to use a Bidirectional LSTM here (to get a single output vector representing your whole document). But there is one thing that will improve your model even further: So far you represent your senteces as squences of chars, which makes it really difficult to make sense of the actual words of your sentence. The better way is usually to use word embeddings like GloVe (which is a good, but simple embedding technique) or more advanced ones like BERT or ELMo.